Bounding the error of the Taylor approximation of $\ln(1.5)$ centered at zero.
Let $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$ and consider the fact that
$$f^{k}(x) = (-1)^{k+1} \frac{(k-1)!}{(x+1)^{k}}$$
The point-wise error in the Taylor approximation of $f$, centered at $c$, truncating after $k$ terms is
\begin{align*}
    E_k(x) = \frac{f^{n+1}(\zeta)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
\end{align*}
for some $\zeta \in (x, c)$. For an approximation of
$\ln(1.5)$ centered at $c=0$, we are asked to find the required $n$ s.t. the error is $\leq 10^{-10}$.  Observe that
Since $f$ is monotonic and increasing, $c$ is the supremum
of $(x, c)$. Then letting $\zeta = c$ guarantees that
\begin{align*}
    E_k(x) \leq f^{(n+1)}(\zeta) \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
\end{align*}
and the error is bounded by
\begin{align*}
    \left|E_k(0.5) \right| &\leq \frac{(0.5)^{n+1}}{n+1} 
\end{align*}
I have struggled to solve the inequality for $n$, to the point that I am doubting whether the preceding results are correct. What is the solution to the inequality in terms of $n$?

Regarding the title: The Taylor approximation of $\ln(1.5)$ is $\ln(1.5)$.  Also, $\ln(x)$ has no Taylor approximation centered at zero.  You're using the Taylor approximation of $\ln(1+x)$, centered at zero, to approximate $\ln(1.5)$.  So the title is a splice of two ideas that don't splice that way.

Exactly solving
$$  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} \leq 10^{-10} $$
is not possible in elementary functions.  It can be solved using Lambert's $W$ function.  The result is then
$$  n \geq \frac{W(10^{10} \ln(2))}{\ln 2} - 1  \text{.}  $$
Of course, you're not supposed to do that.  What you are supposed to do is just plug in a few $n$s to get an idea of how big $n$ needs to be, then test values there to get the laziest (least) $n$ that works.
\begin{align*}
n &= 1  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 0.125  \\
n &= 2  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 0.0416{\dots}  \\
n &= 3  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 0.015625  \\
n &= 4  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 0.00625  \\
\end{align*}
Looks like we get $n/2$ leading zeros.  For $10$ leading zeroes, we should check around $n = 20$.  Note that these are in the order I check, bracketing towards the minimal $n$ giving the desired error bound.  (Different people might be better at this estimating than I am and so arrive at $28$ with fewer steps.)
\begin{align*}
n &= 20  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 2.27{\dots} \times 10^{-8}  \\
n &= 24  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 1.19{\dots} \times 10^{-9}  \\
n &= 26  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 2.75{\dots} \times 10^{-10}  \\
n &= 27  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 1.33{\dots} \times 10^{-10}  \\
n &= 28  :&  \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} &= 6.42{\dots} \times 10^{-11}  \\
\end{align*}
So $n =28$ is the least $n$ giving the desired bound on the error.
A way to get there faster is this: powers of $1/2$ decrease way faster than dividing by $n+1$ does, so just see what power of $1/2$ is less than $10^{-10}$:
$$  \log_{1/2} 10^{-10} = \log_2 10^{10} = 10 \log_2 10 = 33.2{\dots} \text{.} $$
But $33$ is approximately $1.5$ powers of $10$; when we divide by $34$, we remove $10^{1.5}$, so we only need $\log_{1/2} 10^{-8.5} = 28.2{\dots}$.  Then I'd start at the $n = 28$ row of the table above and back up until I found the minimal $n$ giving the desired error bound (which would require checking $n = 28$ and $n = 27$ only).  So one doesn't have to wander around as much -- although if the expression for the error were more complicated, "make a table" is probably the only way to go.

Very clear answer, thank you.

@Eric Towers already gave the exact solution.
You need to find $n$ such that
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1} }{n+1 } \leq 10^{-10}$$ that is to say
$$2^{n+1}\,(n+1) \geq 10^{10}$$ The lhs is very stiff; so, take logarithms and search for the zero of function
$$f(n)=(n+1)\log(2)+\log(n+1)-10\log(10)$$ which is much more linear (just plot it).
For a first estimate, use the very simple bounds
$$\frac {2n}{n+2} < \log(n+1) $$ which reduces to the quadratic
$$\log (2)\,n^2+ (2+3 \log (2)-10 \log(10))\,n+(2 \log (2)-20 \log(10))=0$$ the positive root of which being $29.5170$ which is an upper bound.
Now, use one single iteration of Newton method
$$n_1=n_0-\frac{f(n_0) }{f'(n_0) }$$ This gives $n_1=27.3884$ and then, as an integer, $n=28$.
To give you an idea, $n_2=27.3919$.
